# Why does this line of code in jQuery use li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code why does it use `children('li')` because when you select children it obviously selects all the children.

```
$('ul.emphais').children('li').eq(3).prev().text('added with jQuery');
```

Comment: Yeah you are right.. you can simply write like this too  `$('ul.emphais').children()` The reason why we are passing the li as parameter is to make the code more readable, and dont confuse yourself, passing li as a parameter at this context is completely unnecessary..

Comment: I assume they know exactly the `li` they want to put this data in at all times per each `ul.emphais` because the `.eq(3)` selects the 4rd element out of the elements you have from `.children('li')`. So at that point they only have 1, not all of them. They want to always use the 4th `li` of the `ul` to place this data.

Comment: Because Its in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ul` should ideally contain only `li` as children, `children('li')` will have same meaning as `children()` ideally.

But if you have something like this which is still allowed syntactically (not recommended), it means different:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <div>4<div>
</ul> 

alert($("#list").children("li").length); //Alerts 3 with and without the <div>
alert($("#list").children().length); //Alerts 4 and 3 with and without the <div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3rTL/

Comment: Although putting a `div` inside of a `ul` is invalid, doing so does create a discrepancy between `children("li")` and `children()`. Therefore it's a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, it is allowed syntactically as I mentioned. The point was to show the distinction between `children("li")` and `children()`